# I am trying to remove an inline style which has !important; and I am unable to override it with a custom.css file

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline-code

I have read about jquery statements to turn inline styles off, but well having devoted some time (a few hours) to find an answer I am still stumped.

I can see the inline statements I want to override and can do so temporarily in firebug

the statement below appears inline in two places, I have tried to override with a custom.css file but it won't change.

```
#sp-feature-wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FC0000 !important;
}
```

I have tried looking at a different template to see if I could work around it that way but to no avail so far.

if there is a jquery statement I could use to turn off the inline style (that is created within the template itself not in any of the .css files) for feature wrapper would it go in the custom.css file or would I need to create a file of a different type

Thanks for your assistance.

here is my index.php file below in which I have tried various suggestions(I have been given some great ideas but am lacking the knowledge to impliment, generally getting errors)

```
<?php
 /**
 * @package Helix Framework
 * Template Name - Shaper Helix
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2013 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
//no direct accees
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('resticted aceess'); 

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="<?php echo      $this->language; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"  lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"> <!--  <![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <?php
        $this->helix->Header()
        ->setLessVariables(array(
                'preset'=>$this->helix->Preset(),
                'header_color'=> $this->helix->PresetParam('_header'),
                'bg_color'=> $this->helix->PresetParam('_bg'),
                'text_color'=> $this->helix->PresetParam('_text'),
                'link_color'=> $this->helix->PresetParam('_link'),
                //'footer_color'=> $this->helix-     >PresetParam('_footer')
            ))
        ->addLess('master', 'template')
        ->addLess( 'presets',  'presets/'.$this->helix->Preset() );
    ?>
</head>
<body <?php echo $this->helix->bodyClass('bg hfeed clearfix'); ?>>
    <div class="body-innerwrapper">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div class="chromeframe alert alert-danger" style="text-align:center">You are using   an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a target="_blank" href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</div>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
        $this->helix->layout();
        $this->helix->_Footer();
    ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post your html code

Comment: you can override style attribute with !important;

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles are defined using the style element. You are using the id to add style to the element.

HTML

```
<div id="sp-feature-wrapper" class="sp-feature-class">Test</div>
<div id="sp-feature-inline" style="background-color:green;">Test2</div>
<a href="#;" id="remove">Remove Style Test</a>
```

Jquery

```
$("#remove").on("click",function(){
    $("#sp-feature-wrapper").removeClass("sp-feature-class");
    $("#sp-feature-inline").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Please check the fiddle. Hope this solves your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/29wrX/1/

Comment: Hi Simranjeet, haven't researched where/how to run the HTML code in Joomla, but will try the Jquery in a extension module I've found. thanks

Comment: Hi Simranjeet, your solution looks good just don't know where to start. I assume that the HTML needs to go into my index.php file in the body section. The jQuery part needs to go in a js file? and I need to load jQuery in the head section of hte index.php file? as for the remove on click can it be just $("#remove"),function() - the click was to test? thanks again

Comment: Hi I'm reviewing your org work and a light bulb is starting to go off.. will review/play around some more and then as neccessary post code. otherwise will just say thank you. cheers

Comment: Hi Simranjeet, I have attached a fiddle basically what you posted with a automatically applied change and a questions a to where to locate the code. http://jsfiddle.net/canoeblue/29wrX/3/

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can **override** `style` attribute as

```
#sp-feature-wrapper[style] {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

Or add a new class ***'override'*** to your `div` & use

```
#sp-feature-wrapper.override {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

Or use jQuery as

```
$('#sp-feature-wrapper').css('background', '');
```

Comment: the above code does not work in a custom.css file, it shows up in firebug if I remove the [style], but because the inline style also has !important; it won't override it.

Comment: Hi rohan, I'm using joomla your first suggestion didn't work for me, not sure where to add a new class (haven't researched this yet) and for the third option, I've found a extension module that should allow me to run this so I'm going to try that, thanks

Comment: Hi rohan, tried the jQuery option but have not implimented it correctly, waiting to see if I can get answers on that elsewhere as for the class 'override' looking into how to impliment that.